# Erro ao chamar método no fragmento

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Meu código abaixo era pra fazer uma tarefa simples, ao clicar no botão mudar para outra tela, porém está dando erro:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   chamaCadastro() from the type MainActivity

já alterei o `chamaCadastro` para estático, porém o erro muda para:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   setContentView(int) from the type ActionBarActivity

Segue meu código:

`MainActivity.java`

```java
package br.com.navegandoemtelas;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chamaMenuPrincipal();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

public void chamaMenuPrincipal(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void chamaCadastro(){
    setContentView(R.layout.cadastros);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btCadastro;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        btCadastro = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btCadastrar);
        btCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chamaCadastro();                    
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Eu recomendo criar Classes sempre em arquivos diferentes depois dar import fica muito melhor pra trabalhar e identificar possíveis erros.

Comment: @JamesOrtiz, está fazendo o curso do Neri? Esse jeito de trocar de tela alterando o conteúdo com setContentView é típico dele e é uma má prática. Crie activities ou fragments separados e navegue com startActivity ou mudança de fragment com FragmentManager. E, se for mesmo o curso do Neri, pare já e procure outra fonte :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione isso na classe MainActivity:

```
public static MainActivity context;
```

No construtor, adicione a linha:

```
context = this;
```

E na "chamada", utilize:

```
context.chamaCadastro();
```

Verdade. Fragments **[dentro de uma classe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571010/fragment-inner-class-should-be-static)** devem ser estáticos.

Comment: fiz como disse, porém ao alterar a classe PlaceholderFragment tirando o static, dá erro logo abaixo no public PlaceholderFragment(), o erro é: `This fragment inner class should be static (br.com.navegandoemtelas.MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment)`

Comment: Resposta atualizada.

Comment: Por isso que não se deve utiliza-los dentro de uma classe :P

Comment: Sim. Também recomendo criar uma nova classe.

Comment: Na verdade, um novo arquivo, pois ele por si só é uma classe.

Comment: deixando como estático funcionou blz. Vou experimentar fazer também com arquivos separados, para ver como fica. Agradeço à todos pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Na teoria e na prática o melhor a fazer é o seguinte:

Altere o escopo de seu método o tornando static:

```java
public static void chamaCadastro(){
    setContentView(R.layout.cadastros);
}
```

Crie um arquivo separado chamado `PlaceholderFragment.java` e cole o seguinte código lá, alterando o escopo da classe para `public class`:

```java
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btCadastro;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        btCadastro = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btCadastrar);
        btCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity.chamaCadastro();                    
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Importe a `MainActivity` dentro do `PlaceholderFragment.java` para poder ter acesso aos métodos dela.

Agora você pode acessar o método `MainActivity.chamaCadastro()` da seguinte forma como você viu no código completo acima:

```java
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.chamaCadastro();                    
        }
```

**Obs: apesar de eu não recomendar trocar de layout em uma atividade, é muito melhor você criar uma Activity para cada operação (cadastro/edição) etc.**

Comment: alterando para static, ele passa a dar erro no setContentView = `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setContentView(int) from the type ActionBarActivity`